# Deploy Django App to Azure with Windows Server VM

Tags: django, azure, azure-virtual-machine, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a VM Windows Server 2012 R2 and I would like to deploy a Django application to Azure with it. I connect to this VM remotely and installed IIS.

Can someone write here what packages or features has to be installed on the VM remotely (with steps) and how this will be connected to Azure?

Comment: Can you follow these steps in this [blog](https://medium.com/@ayushi21095/steps-to-deploy-python-django-web-application-on-windows-iis-server-379b2b87fcf9)?

Comment: That is a local one, there is nothing about Azure connection. I can do that, but then how is it connected to Azure web app?

Comment: What do you mean `how is it connected to Azure web app`? Do you want to access the Django application on Azure VM from your web app on Azure App Service?

Comment: yes, something like that.

Comment: Hey Nancy thank you for the effort, I will accept it if it solves my problem, please allow some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found this post which tells everything how to deploy it:
https://www.mattwoodward.com/2016/07/23/running-a-django-application-on-windows-server-2012-with-iis/

Answer (score 1):

To deploy Python Django Web Application on Windows IIS Server, you could refer to this [blog](https://medium.com/@ayushi21095/steps-to-deploy-python-django-web-application-on-windows-iis-server-379b2b87fcf9).

From your comment, you want to access the Django App on Azure VM from your web app on app service. You can take a look at the `networking` feature of the app service plan. You could refer to these documents: [integrate your app with an Azure Virtual Network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) or [Tutorial: integrate Functions with an Azure virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet). vNet Integration allows you to privately access the application on Azure VM in a virtual network.

> VNet Integration gives your web app access to resources in your
>   virtual network but doesn't grant inbound private access to your web
>   app from the virtual network. Private site access refers to making
>   your app only accessible from a private network such as from within an
>   Azure virtual network. VNet Integration is only for making outbound
>   calls from your app into your VNet.